# Android PopupMenu setGravity (API < 19)

Tags: android, menu

In Android API 19 was added contructor of PopupMenu which allows specify gravity.

> [public PopupMenu (Context context, View anchor, int gravity)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html#PopupMenu(android.content.Context,%20android.view.View,%20int))

How i can set gravity in older versions?

Comment: please answer this haha

Answer (score 9):

Change line `import android.widget.PopupMenu;` to import `android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;`

Comment: Or if you're using `androidx` then use `import androidx.appcompat.widget.PopupMenu;` and it'll work

Answer (score 1):

you can use rtl for giving gravity to right [here is link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.tr/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)

RTL was started to support at Android 4.2

or you can create a custom popupmenu and inflate it.

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            popup = new PopupMenu(context, arg1,Gravity.CENTER );
            //popupWindow.showAtLocation(anchor, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, xPos, yPos);     
        }
        //Inflating the Popup using xml file  
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.listmenu, popup.getMenu());
```

or you can give anchor and style

```
showPopup(viewOfWherePopupmenuShows,popmenuNameList.size());


PopupMenu popMenu = new PopupMenu(Activity.this,v)
int size =popmenuNameList.size();
for(int i =0; i <size; i++){
 popMenu.getMenu().add(popmenuNameList.get(i)).setIcon(R.drawable.logo);

}
 popMenu.show();

protected void showPopupMenu(View v, int size){
   //create instance
   PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(Activity.this,v);
   //inflating the popup using xml
   popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_popup_list),popup.getMenu());
}
```

The style of menu is determined by the style of context you pass. So all you need to do is to pass your Activity reference as context

style here;

```
 <style name="style" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">

    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">...</item>
    <item name="android:popupAnimationStyle">...</item>
   <item name="android:popupBackground">...</item>

</style>
```